# how to update Sql database from all Rows of DataGridview?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a form where I have one DataGridView and I am loading values from SQL database. I am trying to update all rows specified cells data in SQL which are inserted in DataGridView. I wrote the following code but it is updating only one row data to SQL database. How can I do this?

```
Using cmd7 As New SqlCommand("update stockdata set available = @available , 
qty = @qty where itemcode = @itemcode", cn)


For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
cmd7.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells(0).Value

cmd7.Parameters.Add("@available", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "no"
cmd7.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0"
cn.Open()
cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
Next

End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very happy to see Using blocks, Parameters and the .Add method identifying the data type. You keep adding the same parameters over again until poor old cmd7 had so many parameters it didn't know what to do. :-) The only thing that needed to be changed was the `.Value` of the @itemcode. So, the only thing we need to do is refer to that member of the parameters collection that we already added outside the loop, and set its value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection String")
        Using cmd7 As New SqlCommand("update stockdata set available = @available , qty = @qty where itemcode = @itemcode", cn)
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@available", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "no"
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0"
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cn.Open()
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                cmd7.Parameters("@itemcode").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
                cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: not tested though.(Just loop the loop through all the rows in the datagridview)

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Using cmd7 As New SqlCommand("update stockdata set available = @available , qty = @qty where itemcode = @itemcode", cn)

            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells(0).Value

            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@available", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "no"

            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0"

            cn.Open()

            cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cn.Close()
        End Using
    Next
```

Comment: Can you explain why the OP code was not working and yours will work?